# Why does removal of primitive arrays from Java Collection by value not work?

Tags: java

Here is the minimum working example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Scratchpad {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<int[]> collection = new HashSet<>();
        
        collection.add(new int[]{1,2});
        collection.remove(new int[]{1,2});

        System.out.println(collection.size());
        assert collection.size() == 1;
    }
}
```

The same works for if the items in the collection are of type `List` (which implements the `equals` method of course).

My suspicion is that it's because array are special objects that does not implement `equals`? (If that's case, I feel a little sad that array doesn't get as well documented as other standard library objects, at least not in the Java Docs for the standard lib)

Comment: all Objects have an implementation of equals (it's inherited from Object). But it's not further implemented, hence they check whether the reference in the memory is the same, not the value

Comment: @Stultuske Got it, thanks. It's a little hard to find out cuz it's not in the standard lib's documentation.

Comment: It would work if you passed in the same array, but you pass in a different array with the same contents. Different arrays with the same contents are not equal in Java.

Comment: @Kun what isn't? It's in the documentation of Object. It's the basics of the equals method.

Comment: It actually is in the docs. Since `equals()` is public the method is inherited by all objects and if they don't override that method the version in `Object` is used. And the JavaDoc on that one states: "This method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object(x == y has the value true)."

Comment: @Stultuske The documentation of Object can't tell us if a subclass has overriden it. Only the documentation for that particular subcalss can show.

Comment: @Kun it's well known that Arrays don't have their own implementation.

Comment: Well-known to a Java guru, sure. But it's just not very beginner-friendly, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question but having it marked as a duplicated has banned me from asking further questions here.

Comment: @Kun further questions shouldn't be asked here, they should be asked in other questions.

Comment: I don't think it is a bad question either, but it is a duplicate.  I can't tell if you have been banned from asking questions or not, but it you have it won't be a result of a single duplicate.  (In fact I think that a dup with no + or - votes will be neutral wrt to question bans.  The algorithms are not published ...)

Comment: @Stultuske How do you mean? Like in comments?

Comment: @Kun no. as in create a new question, just like you created this one

Comment: @user15793316 it is mentioned as 'inherited from' in the documentation of every class, but there is no documentations of int[] (for instance)